# Apply css on anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight(for few seconds) an anchor tag which is placed in li tag on success of an Ajax request. How can I achieve this via Jquery.

this is anchor tag, which is used in my code:

```
<li class="active">
  <a id="firstTab" data-toggle="tab" href="#adviceContent">
    <i class="icon-large icon-info-sign " ></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Highlight in what way? Background color?

Comment: Yep, some Background color.

Comment: what have you done so far, show workaround

Comment: I have tried this:    $('.highlightSelected').css('background','yellow').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(2000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax success funciton:

```
jQuery('#firstTab').css('background-color','#ccc');
setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery('#firstTab').css('background-color','transparent');
},2000);
```

If you want the color change to be animated, check out [jQuery UI Color Animation](http://api.jqueryui.com/color-animation/)

Answer (score 2):

Call jQuery-UI from Google or jQuery CDN.

And try this on your Ajax success:

```
var color = $("#firstTab").css("background-color");
var highlightColor = '#bebebe';

$("#firstTab").animate({backgroundColor:highlightColor},500,function(){
   $(this).delay(1000).animate({backgroundColor:color},500);
});
```

You can check this [Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/scpgY/)

Comment: This answer is also perfect.